# Password protect entries on a form

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to add a password onto a form's entries once they've been submitted?

For example, I've created an employee exit survey form for our staff that will be no longer employed with the agency. If there's more than one person that has access to the Cognito Forms account, is there a way to password protect the entries on that form only, so that only the password holders can access the entries on that form?

Answer (score 2):

In [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/), you have the ability to set permissions for individual forms in addition to general user permissions. To do this:

1. Click your organization's name in the top right corner and select the gear icon to open the organization settings.
2. From your settings, find the Users section and select the user that should not have access to the employee exit entries.
3. From the user's page, you can set their permissions for specific forms. In this case, set the user permission as None so that they cannot view the form or its entries:

[image]

4. Repeat this process for the rest of the users that you wish to restrict.